# Dropdown-menu not top most

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some difficulty with a `data-toggle="dropdown"`. It opens, but renders only inside the `div` in resides, as demonstrated by the image below:

[image]

Some of the HTML:

```
<div class="row pull-right">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs btn-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="" ng-click="vm.doSomeStuff(args)">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown css:

[image]

Any way I can get around this?

Codepen example: [example](http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/dpOZmG)

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like the typical overflow:hidden issue.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply. I tried changing the `overflow` to visible, with no effect. Unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Show a full, testable example please. [mcve]

Comment: Not so easy, since with is part of a larger project and has various dependencies :sigh:

Comment: @CBroe added a code pen... Although it's working in the example :sigh:

Comment: @CBroe got the code pen to replicate the issue

Comment: There’s overflow:hidden set in two places, on your div `#foo`, and its `.slimScrollDiv` parent element – you will need to remove it from both, if you want this to work. But then of course you want have a scrollbar in that element any more, resp. setting a fixed height does not make much sense. I think your best bet is to make that dropdown menu not be part of the scrolling container element, but put it outside of it – and then get it to overlay it in the correct position.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the advice and the reply, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by the `slimScroll` aka `fullScroll` directive, which adds the following inline styles (during run-time):

The following [codepen](http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/dpOZmG), demonstrates the issue...

```
 <div full-scroll style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
    <div class="full-height-scroll">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="slimScrollBar"></div>
    <div class="slimScrollRail"></div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
/**
 * fullScroll - Directive for slimScroll with 100%
 */
function fullScroll($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.slimscroll({
                    height: '100%',
                    railOpacity: 0.9
                });

            });
        }
    };
}
```

Added inline styles:
[image]

**[UPDATE]**

The following fixes the issue:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-link" aria-expanded="false" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="vm.doSomeStuff(ms)">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```